# Database delete query between two tables with a foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a Profile(as shown in below image) Table Which whenever I try to remove a row from it, I face this error which indicates there is still data in foreign key in Tempprice table which is related to the Id in Lots table .

the problem is when its Lots table turn to Delete , there is still rows in Tempprice which have different Userid but same lotsid that have Ownerid or Winnerid which I want to Delete.

And I don't know how to delete this rows!? or which query is needed?

**Database Relationships and Tables:**
[image: Database Relationships]

**Code**:

```
while (checkbox.Checked)
{
    // Retreive the  ID
    int ida = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);

    // Pass the  value of the selected Id(s) to the Delete //command.

    //These numbers indicate in which order tables shoulde be deleted  
    /*1*/
    new BLL.LoginBLL().Delete(ida);
    /*2*/
    new BLL.MessageBLL().Delete(ida);
    /*3*/
    new BLL.JointBLL().Delete(ida);                    
    /*4*/
    new BLL.TemppriceBLL().Delete(ida);                             
    /*5*/
    new BLL.LotsBLL().Delete(ida);    
    /*6*/      
    new BLL.AuctionBLL().Delete(ida);
    /*7*/
    new BLL.ProfileBLL().DeleteProfile(ida);

    checkbox.Checked = false;
}

ShowUsers();
```

Comment: Can you give us the table structures as proper SQL code - this picture is just too small to read anything........

Comment: View image in new tab shows readable size.

Comment: I'd hardly call 5 pt font "readable"

Comment: @marc_s How do I generate Sql code of diagram?

Comment: @marc_s and @ McKay bigger image of needed table:http://i.imgur.com/vUVlr.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To delete references, you need to set the relation (by selecting the line connecting the two objects) to Cascade for the `End 1 On Delete` property.
Then you need to `Load` the referenced object or collection. Calling Delete in this case, will delete your object and all objects it references.

Comment: Then you have to manually delete all other related references.

Comment: how? I mean with which query?

Comment: Answer:                                                            first - Delete From Tempprice Where Lotid IN(Select Id From Lot Where  Ownerid=Profile-Id )
after that - Delete From Lot Where  Ownerid=Profile-Id